# Breaking bricks with chain reaction

Tags: java

I am developing a game in java just for fun. It is a ball brick breaking game of some sort.

[image]

Here is a level, when the ball hits one of the Orange bricks I would like to create a chain reaction to explode all other bricks that are NOT gray(unbreakable) and are within reach of the brick being exploded.

So it would clear out everything in this level without the gray bricks.

I am thinking I should ask the brick that is being exploded for other bricks to the LEFT, RIGHT, UP, and DOWN of that brick then start the same process with those cells.

---

//NOTE TO SELF: read up on Enums and List

When a explosive cell is hit with the ball it calls the explodeMyAdjecentCells();

//This is in the Cell class

```
public void explodeMyAdjecentCells() {

    exploded = true;

    ballGame.breakCell(x, y, imageURL[thickness - 1][0]);

    cellBlocks.explodeCell(getX() - getWidth(),getY());
    cellBlocks.explodeCell(getX() + getWidth(),getY());
    cellBlocks.explodeCell(getX(),getY() - getHeight());
    cellBlocks.explodeCell(getX(),getY() + getHeight());

    remove();

    ballGame.playSound("src\\ballgame\\Sound\\cellBrakes.wav", 100.0f, 0.0f, false, 0.0d);

}
```

//This is the CellHandler->(CellBlocks)

```
public void explodeCell(int _X, int _Y) {


    for(int c = 0; c < cells.length; c++){

        if(cells[c] != null && !cells[c].hasExploded()) {

            if(cells[c].getX() == _X && cells[c].getY() == _Y) {

                int type = cells[c].getThickness();

                if(type != 7 && type != 6 && type != 2) {

                    cells[c].explodeMyAdjecentCells();
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

It successfully removes my all adjacent cells,

But in the explodeMyAdjecentCells() method, I have this line of code

```
ballGame.breakCell(x, y, imageURL[thickness - 1][0]);
```

//

This line tells the ParticleHandler to create 25 small images(particles) of the exploded cell.

Tough all my cells are removed the particleHandler do not create particles for all the removed cells.

---

**The problem was solved youst now, its really stupid.
I had set particleHandler to create max 1500 particles. My god how did i not see that!**

```
private int particleCellsMax = 1500;
private int particleCellsMax = 2500;
```

thx for all the help people, I will upload the source for creating the particles youst for fun if anyone needs it.

The source code for splitting image into parts was taken from:
[Kalani's Tech Blog](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html)

//Particle Handler

```
public void breakCell(int _X, int _Y, String URL) {

    File file = new File(URL);

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis);

    int rows = 5;
    int colums = 5;

    int parts = rows * colums;

    int partWidth = image.getWidth() / colums;
    int partHeight = image.getHeight() / rows;

    int count = 0;

    BufferedImage imgs[] = new BufferedImage[parts];

    for(int x = 0; x < colums; x++) {

        for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {

            imgs[count] = new BufferedImage(partWidth, partHeight, image.getType());

            Graphics2D g = imgs[count++].createGraphics();

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, partWidth, partHeight, partWidth * y, partHeight * x, partWidth * y + partWidth, partHeight * x + partHeight, null);
            g.dispose();
        }
    }

    int numParts = imgs.length;
    int c = 0;

    for(int iy = 0; iy < rows; iy ++) {

        for(int ix = 0; ix < colums; ix++) {

            if(c < numParts) {

                Image imagePart = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imgs[c].getSource());
                createCellPart(_X + ((image.getWidth() / colums) * ix), _Y + ((image.getHeight() / rows) * iy), c, imagePart);

                c++;

            } else {

                break;
            }
        }
    }


    } catch(IOException io) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine a method that would recursively get all touching cells of a similar color.
Then you can operate on that list (of all touching blocks) pretty easily and break all the ones are haven't been broken.

Also note that your getAdjentCell() method has side effects (it does the breaking) which isn't very intuitive based on the name.

```
// I agree with Matt that color (or type) should probably be an enum, 
// or at least a class.  int isn't very descriptive
public enum CellType { GRAY, RED, ORANGE }

public class Cell{
....
    public final CellType type;

    /**
     * Recursively find all adjacent cells that have the same type as this one.
     */
    public List<Cell> getTouchingSimilarCells() {
        List<Cell> result = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        result.add(this);
        for (Cell c : getAdjecentCells()) {
            if (c != null && c.type == this.type) {
                result.addAll(c.getTouchingSimilarCells());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Get the 4 adjacent cells (above, below, left and right).<br/>
     * NOTE: a cell may be null in the list if it does not exist.
     */
    public List<Cell> getAdjecentCells() {
        List<Cell> result = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        result.add(cellBlock(this.getX() + 1, this.getY()));
        result.add(cellBlock(this.getX() - 1, this.getY()));
        result.add(cellBlock(this.getX(), this.getY() + 1));
        result.add(cellBlock(this.getX(), this.getY() - 1));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize that enums is the better way to go. Tough I have little experience with Enums and using List, I would have to read up on it. I rewrote my code a little bit(view in top) and the problem that i am been having all along is that, all the cells are being removed but not all are being removed with an effect(particle handler)..would you be so kind to look over the updated code. thx

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider looking at this in a more OO way, and using 'tell don't ask'.  So you would look at having a Brick class, which would know what its colour was, and its adjacent blocks.  Then you would tell the first Block to explode, it would then know that if it was Orange (and maybe consider using Enums for this - not just numbers), then it would tell its adjacent Blocks to 'chain react' (or something like that), these blocks would then decide what to do (either explode in the case of an orange block - and call their adjacent blocks, or not in the case of a grey Block.

I know its quite different from what your doing currently, but will give you a better structured program hopefully.

Comment: Thanks, I realize that enums is the better way to go. Tough I have little experience with Enums and using List, I would have to read up on it.